# Discrete Mathematics DFA Finite State Digram Problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I am solving a finite state diagram problem where $w$ alternates $a$'s and $b$'s and has an even number of $b$'s. In my solution I had this basically.

[image: DFA]

I was just wondering if this is acceptable because this returns even $b$'s and isn't it alternating with $a$'s? Also just swap $a$'s and $b$'s from the pic.

Answer (score 1):

The DFA pictured here, but with $a$ and $b$ swapped everywhere, accepts every word over the alphabet $\{a,b\}$ that has an even number of $b$s, whether or not the word alternates $a$s and $b$s. For example, it accepts $bb$, which it clearly should not. I suggest trying again with four states, say $q_0,q_1,q_2$, and $q_3$. Design it so that the machine is in

- state $q_0$ initially and when it has just read a $b$ that brings the total number of $b$s to an even number;
- state $q_1$ when it has just read an $a$, and the total number of $b$s read so far is even;
- state $q_2$ when it has just read a $b$, and the total number of $b$s read so far is odd; and
- state $q_3$ when it has just read an $a$, and the total number of $b$s read so far is odd.

I’ll leave it to you to work out the transitions and to determine which states should be acceptor states.